# Get distinct values from parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've got a parse.com back-end with some tables:

```
shop
product
shopHasProduct
  Shop:Shop Pointer;
  Product:Product pointer; 
  + some fields relation to shop-specific info
```

So `shopHasProduct` is a many-to-many table.

What I need, is to get all the `product` that is not in `shopHasProduct` table for a specific `shop`.

What i've done so far is (query is on `shopHasProduct` table):

```
[query whereKey:@"Shop" notEqualTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"currentShop"]];
[query includeKey:@"Product"];

PFQuery *shopHasProductThisShop = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"shopHasProduct"];
[shopHasProductThisShop whereKey:@"Shop" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"currentShop"]];

PFQuery *finalQ = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"shopHasProduct"];
[finalQ whereKey:@"Product" doesNotMatchKey:@"Product" inQuery:shopHasProductThisShop];
[finalQ includeKey:@"Product"];

return finalQ;//query;
```

That gets me all the products, that are not in the current shop. But the products are there for each shop, so they are reoccurring.

How do I sort them so they are distinct?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up not using `PFQueryTableViewController` but a normal `UITableViewController`

in viewDidLoad  I do the following:

```
PFQuery *shopHasProductThisShop = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"shopHasProduct"];
[shopHasProductThisShop whereKey:@"Shop" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"currentShop"]];



PFQuery *hej = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"shopHasProduct"];
[hej whereKey:@"Product" doesNotMatchKey:@"Product" inQuery:shopHasProductThisShop];
[hej includeKey:@"Product"];

[hej findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *allProducts, NSError *error) {

    self.productToAdd = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.productArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSLog(@"Hvor mange er der i alle prodikter'et:%d", [allProducts count]);

    for (PFObject *object in allProducts) {

        PFObject *random = object[@"Product"];
        [self.productArray addObject:random];

    }
    NSSet *uniqueStates = [NSSet setWithArray:[self.productArray valueForKey:@"objectId"]];

    NSArray *foobar = [uniqueStates allObjects];
    for (NSString *string in foobar) {
        PFObject *hulo = [PFQuery getObjectOfClass:@"Product" objectId:string];
        [self.productToAdd addObject:hulo];
    }  
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

So I get an NSMutableArray with only distinct products.